# Calculate the surface integral $\iint_S (\nabla \times F)\cdot dS$ over a part of a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

How can I calculate the integral $$\iint_S (\nabla \times F)\cdot dS$$
where $S$  is the part of the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y+z\ge 1$, $F=(y-z, z-x, x-y)$.

I calculated that $\nabla\times F=(-2 , -2 ,-2)$. It's difficult for me to find the section between the sphere and the plane. Also, I can't calculate the integral.

**Update**: I found that the result is: $-6π/3^{1/2}$. Ιs it correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Comment: Are you sure you are meant to calculate the surface integral, and not use Stokes? Perhaps the best approach is to use Stokes *twice* (surface to curve to surface), where the second surface is a part of the *plane* bounded by the sphere.

Comment: I found that the result is: -6π/(3^(1/2)). Ιs it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The result $-6\pi /\sqrt{3}$ appears to be close, but not quite correct. I'll recheck using the approach from comment:

> use Stokes twice (surface to curve to surface), where the second surface is a part of the plane bounded by the sphere.

The plane has unit normal vector $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$. The dot product with the field $\nabla \times F$ is $-2\sqrt{3}$. So, the flux is $-2\sqrt{3}$ times the area of the part of the plane within the sphere. This part is a disk of radius... let's see.

On the plane $x+y+z=1 $, the point  $A=(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ is orthogonal to the vector $OA$. Hence, the Pythagorean theorem implies that the disk is centered at A and has radius $\sqrt{1-|OA|^2}= \sqrt{1-1/3} = \sqrt{2/3}$. So its area is $2\pi/3$.

**Conclusion**: the flux is $-4\pi/\sqrt{3}$.

It would be $-6\pi /\sqrt{3}$ if the plane was $x+y+z=0$, for then its part within the sphere would have radius $1$.