# Intersection of a sphere and a plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How can I find the intersection between the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $x+y+z=1?$

#### Context

This is related to a computation of surface integral using Stokes' theorem, [Calculate the surface integral $\iint_S (\nabla \times F)\cdot dS$ over a part of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096613/)

Comment: @AlexSilva The point (1,1,1) is not on the plane nor is it on the sphere.

Comment: Sorry! I thought it was $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 3$ and $x+y+z = 3$.

Comment: Without context, you may get correct answers that are not useful for your purpose. It would help to specify that you are after a parametric equation, for the purpose of integration.

Answer (score 3):

If we visualize it, it's pretty easy to believe that the intersection should be a circle living in space.

[image]

The real question is, what type of description do you want?  Here are a few possibilities.

Clearly, the circle lies in the plane, which has normal vector $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$.
Also, symmetry dictates that the center must lie on the line where $x=y=z$.  Since the center is on the plane $x+y+z=1$, we have the center is $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$.  The radius is just the distance between center and any known point on the circle, like $(1,0,0)$.  Thus, the radius is $r=\sqrt{2/3}$.  I would say that this center, radius, and normal provide a complete description of the circle.

Another alternative is to provide a parametrization.  This can be accomplished via
$$p(t) = c + r\cos(t)u + r\sin(t)v,$$
where $c$ is the center, $r$ is the radius, and $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular unit vectors that are both perpendicular to the normal vector for the plane.  Specifically,
$$p(t) = \langle 1/3,1/3,1/3 \rangle + \cos(t)\langle 1,-1,0 \rangle/\sqrt{3} + 
\sin(t)\langle 1,1,-2 \rangle/3.$$
That's the parametrization I used to create the image.

Comment: I added context to the question; the OP needs parametric form.

Comment: @Fundamental Then it's a good thing I provided it!

Comment: +1: Nice visualisation. How did you do it?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. If you hit the edit button, you'll see the Mathematica code embedded in a comment.

Comment: Thanks! Will be plagiarising your code for future visualisations :-).

Comment: @copper.hat No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)+(u,v,w)$ you are left with the constraints $u+v+w=0$ and $u^2+v^2+w^2=\frac{2}{3}$, from which it follows that $u^2+uv+v^2=\frac{1}{3}$ and $w=-(u+v)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a change of coordinates. Let $Q = \begin{bmatrix} 
{1 \over \sqrt{3}} & {1 \over \sqrt{2}} & {1 \over \sqrt{6}} \\
{1 \over \sqrt{3}} & -{1 \over \sqrt{2}} & {1 \over \sqrt{6}} \\
{1 \over \sqrt{3}} & 0 & -{2 \over \sqrt{6}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $Q$ is orthogonal, $Q^T Q = I$, and
$Q (1,0,0)^T = {1 \over \sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)^T$.

The purpose is to rotate the plane so that it is perpendicular to the $x$ axis. Any suitable rotation will do, this was the easiest for me to compute.

The surface of the sphere is invariant under rotations, so this works nicely.

Let $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \|x\|=1 \}$, $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \langle (1,1,1)^T , x \rangle =1 \}$. Since $Q$ is orthogonal, we have
$Q D = D$, and we have $P = Q P'$, where $P'=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{3}} \}$.

Hence $D \cap P = Q (D \cap P') $. We see that
$D \cap P' = \{ ( {1 \over \sqrt{3}}, x_2,x_3)^T | x_2^2+x_3^2 = 1-{1 \over 3} \} $.

Consequently we have $D \cap P = Q \{ ({1 \over \sqrt{3}}, \sqrt{2 \over 3} \cos \theta, \sqrt{2 \over 3} \sin \theta ) \}_{\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)}$

Answer (score 0):

compute the intersection point of the line $\vec{x}=(0;0;0)+t(1;1;1)$ with the given plane. This is the midpoint of a circle (if he exists).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets
$\ds{\quad\vec{n}_{1}
     = {1 \over \root{3}}\,\pars{1,1,1}\,,\quad
     \vec{n}_{2}={1 \over \root{6}}\,\pars{2,-1,-1}\quad}$
and $\ds{\quad\vec{n}_{3} = \vec{n}_{1}\times\vec{n_{2}}\ .\quad}$

> It is clear that
>   $\ds{\vec{n}_{i}\cdot\vec{n}_{j}=\delta_{ij}\,.\quad}$ Lets
>   $\ds{\quad\vec{r}\equiv\pars{x,y,z}=
>     {1 \over \root{3}}\,\vec{n}_{1} + \mu_{2}\,\vec{n}_{2} + \mu_{3}\,\vec{n}_{3}
>     \quad}$
>   which satisfies $\ds{x + y + z = 1}$. In addition, $\ds{r^{2} = 1}$ yields

$$
{1 \over 3} + \mu_{2}^{2} + \mu_{3}^{2}= 1\qquad\imp\qquad
{2 \over 3}=\mu_{2}^{2} + \mu_{3}^{2}
=\verts{\vec{r} - {\root{3} \over 3}\,\vec{n}_{1}}^{2}
$$

---

It's equivalent to
$$
\pars{x - {\root{3} \over 3}}^{2} + \pars{y - {\root{3} \over 3}}^{2}
+\pars{z - {\root{3} \over 3}}^{2}=\pars{\root{6} \over 3}^{2}
$$

> It describes a circle with center at
>   $\ds{\quad\pars{{\root{3} \over 3},{\root{3} \over 3},{\root{3} \over 3}}\quad}$
>   and radius $\ds{\quad{\root{6} \over 3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Because someone has to: An algebraic geometry approach. Let,

$$
\begin{align*}
p &:= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1,\\
q &:= x + y + z -1.
\end{align*}
$$

Form the ideal,

$$
I = \left< p, q\right> \subset \mathbb{R}\left[x,y,z\right].
$$

A Groebner basis for this ideal, with respect to a degree reverse lexicographic order, is then,

$$
G = \left< y^2 + yz + z^2 - y - z, x + y + z - 1 \right>.
$$

The first polynomial in $G$ has two variables and the second has three. Fix an $x$; you are left with two polynomials in two unknowns.